# Take webpage screenshot after a certain interval of time

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webpage-screenshot

I have written a chrome extension which could take the visible tab's screenshot. Now, I want the extension to take pictures automatically after a certain interval of time without pressing the button. How could that be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be pretty simple, just use the standard methods in Javascript `setTimeout` and `setInterval`.

```
var seconds = 10 * 1000;
var windowId = some window id;
setTimeout(function() { 
  chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(
    some window id, 
    {}, 
    function () { ... do something with the screen shot ;} )
  }
, seconds);
```

This will take a screenshot after 10 seconds.  To take a screenshot of the visible tab every to seconds use `setInterval`

```
var seconds = 10 * 1000;
var windowId = some window id;
setInterval(function() { 
  chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(
    some window id, 
    {}, 
    function () { ... do something with the screen shot ;} )
  }
, seconds);
```